# Confusion in understanding wave number

Tags: waves, units, dimensional-analysis, wavelength

The [wave number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) is the number of complete wave cycles in a meter.
So,

$$K = \frac{1m}{\lambda}$$

and also,

$$K = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$

so according to both of the above equation how is

$$2\pi = 1m \, .$$

Comment: There's no question here. Also, your statement that $K = 1\text{m} / \lambda$ is completely false. The wave number is just $2 \pi / \lambda$. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $\lambda$ is the wavelength and already carries a unit of length. So when you define $K=\frac{1m}{\lambda}$, this quantity would be dimensionless. And as you say, this really would be the number of cycles in one meter. But this is not the definition of wavenumber. The wavenumber and also the frequency are a measure of cycles in space/time *per* unit length/time.

There are two conventions frequently used:

1. **Angular frequency** $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$ with period $T$ and **(Angular) wavenumber** $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ with wavelength $\lambda$
2. **Frequency** $\nu=f=\tfrac{1}{T}=\tfrac{\omega}{2\pi}$ and **(spectroscopic) wavenumber** $\tilde{\nu}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

The first one is common in physics (at least I only ever worked with those) while the second is frequently used in more technical/applied branches.

To answer your question: No, $2\pi\neq 1m$, which should be clear from dimensions alone. Instead your two $K$'s are not the same quantity.

Different people in different branches use different conventions. Be aware of that; it can spare you many frustrations.

Comment: I know that that was one of the reason i asked it, but here is what you get when you search wave number on google which confused me "The term wave number refers to the number of complete wave cycles of an electromagnetic field (EM field) that exist in one meter (1 m) of linear space."

Comment: @Akash Glad we could clear that up!